# How to run Bitcoin's autogen.sh file?

Tags: bash, github, command-line, sh, bitcoin

I'm following along in Andreas Antonopoulos Bitcoin book [Mastering Bitcoin](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032281.do) Chapter 3 (The Bitcoin client)

And am at the part where I've cloned the [Bitcoin github project](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

I've checked out v0.9.3rc2

Now the next step in the book is below:

*Assuming the prerequisites are installed, you start the build process by generating a set of build scripts using the autogen.sh script.*

```
$ ./ autogen.sh configure.ac: 12: installing ` src/ build-aux/ config.guess' 
configure.ac: 12: installing ` src/ build-aux/ config.sub' 
configure.ac: 37: installing ` src/ build-aux/ install-sh' 
configure.ac: 37: installing ` src/ build-aux/ missing' 
src/ Makefile.am: installing ` src/ build-aux/ depcomp'
$
```

Trying the following commands, but nothing works

```
./autogen.sh
autogen.sh
sh autogen.sh
bash autogen.sh
```

I keep getting:

```
./autogen.sh: line 5: autoreconf: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**
Thanks to [@nu11p01n73R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150943/nu11p01n73r) and also reading the osx doc I installed [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then installed autoconf, worked! Now I tried to run the autogen.sh file again and am getting a new error:

```
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try installing `autoconf` from repo

Comment: Thanks @nu11p01n73R! 1 step ahead, but now a new error :(

Comment: Try installing `automake` as well

Comment: Sweet that worked! :D I forgot to install all the needed dependancies, wasn't sure what autogen was, didn't think it was one of them. Want to post your answer as an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `autoconf` and `automake` would solve the issue